# Uncheck checkboxes in parent context

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I'm trying to uncheck checkboxes, with something like this

```
$(':checkbox:checked').prop('checked',false);
```

But it ocurred that i'm in other context and I can catch it by

```
this.window.parent.document;
```

I would like to connect both like

```
var z = this.window.parent.document;
z.(':checkbox:checked').prop('checked',false);
```

But I have no clue how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap `z` with jQuery `$()` and use `.find()`

```
$(z).find(':checkbox:checked').prop('checked',false);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, both Answers were good but your's was first

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this.window.parent.document).find(':checkbox:checked').prop('checked',false);
```

Like that ;)